# Why would an authoritative BIND server deny authority?

Tags: bind

I have a user who brought me a question I sure as heck can't resolve.

```
(1) Domain X.ORG is properly registered and has two name servers (NS1.Q.TLD and NS2.Q.TLD) listed as authoritative.
(2) Both NS1.Q.TLD and NS2.Q.TLD properly resolve with public IP addresses.
(3) My user, using nslookup queried both NS1 and NS2. Both resolved what he was looking for http://www.x.org
(4) But when the user queried our BIND server and others, such as Google's, he gets:"server can't find http://www.x.org: NXDOMAIN"
```

I ran dig on both NS1 and NS2. While both answered, BOTH report **AUTHORITY as 0.**

```
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
```

**How can the authoritative server deny authority?**

Posts: 19
Joined: 2013-01-29 10:26

Answer (score 0):

The domain is listed as under: server hold
The domain is on This status code is set by your domain's Registry Operator. Your domain is not activated in the DNS.